# How can we achieve coverflow view in android titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

I have seen that titanium support CoverFlowView in titanium but it works only on ios, Can anyone have idea to achieve CoverFlow in android with titanium

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are in luck!  Someone already built a coverflow module for Android using the Android development environment.

https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow

You need to be willing to write the additional code for that to turn it into a module for Titanium.
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Android_Module_Development_Guide

It should be possible, but I must admit I've never tried to write one myself.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you cannot get Coverflow on Android. Since it is a native iOs component which is not implemented in Android at all. Frameworks like Titanium always "link" your commands to internal system APIs. When there is no API there is no way to access it. Of course you could try to build it on your own but I think this would not work that well. And its a lot of work!

Additionally cover flow is not really useful (except for holding just a few items). Have a look at [my question at ux.stackexchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/69814/should-i-still-use-cover-flow).